# How to disable spell checking or equivalent features in TeXmaker/TeXstudio?

Tags: texmaker, spelling, texstudio, ide

The spell checker is really good when I type English words. However I am a Chinese user and it always annoys me when I type `Chinese` words since they are treated as misspelled. So how can I disable spell checking in TeXmaker/TeXstudio or something equivalent to that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to menu `Options`.
2. Select `Configure TeXstudio...`.
3. Check `Show advanced options` and select `Editor` tab. Note: There is a puzzle that you must answer correctly to show the advanced options, the answer is 3.
4. Uncheck `Inline spell checking`.
5. Click `OK` and done.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to run the spell checker so that it ignores anything in the align environment? (not necessarily for the inline checking).

Comment: Is there a way to ingore only a single work that is ignored by the user? @kiss my armpit

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post, but the puzzle you mentioned seems no longer present in newer versions of the software. Do you remember what the puzzle is? I'm REALLY curious.